# sending metadata with red5 does not work

Tags: actionscript-3, stream, metadata, red5

I have a fully working red5 (1.0 version) server that relay live streams from webcams.
However, when I send metadata to red5 , I can see (with a sniffing program) those metadata info going to red5 server, But other clients playing the webcam stream never get those metadata just like red5 doesn't relay them.

here is the sending brodcaster code:

```
if (event.info.code == "NetStream.Publish.Start")
sendMetadata();
```

and the sendMetadata function :

```
function sendMetadata()
{
var metaData:Object = new Object();

metaData.duration = 0;
metaData.filesize = 0;
metaData.framerate = fpsx;
metaData.width = large;
metaData.height = haute;
metaData.stereo = 0;
metaData.videocodecid = 7;
metaData.videodatarate = "800";

ns.send("@setDataFrame", "onMetaData", metaData);

}
```

now on playing clients reading the incoming stream , I just added this function to listen for metadatas when opening the stream :

```
function onMetaData(infoObject:Object):void 
{ 
   var key:String; 
   for (key in infoObject) 
   { 
      ExternalInterface.call("alerter", "" +key + ": " + infoObject[key]); 
   } 
}
```

this function is never called , meaning incoming stream does not contain metadata.

please help me tuning red5 so all subscribing clients to the webcam stream can read the metadatas send once at start by the publisher

Thanks,

Comment: Try version 1.0.5, I don't remember when we fixed this.

Comment: I tried with red5 1.0.5. and metadata is not transmitted. while with wowza and exacty the same code for publisher , it transmit the metadata and clients can read metadata. there must be a problem with red5 I think